# Replicating google auto complete with jquery autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqaXN.png]

Trying to accomplish the above result with jquery.googleSuggest.js is giving me a lot of trouble as can be seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/883xbxdy/). Some of the original CSS of jquery UI seems to be shining tough. Anyone any hints on the most elegant way to fix this?  (And how to add the grey "gle", after "goo" behavior in the screenshot above?)

HTML

```
 <div class="suggestions_box">
    <ul>
     <li>f<b>acebook</b></li>
     <li>f<b>unda</b></li>
    </ul> 
  </div>
```

JS

```
var div = $("<div>").appendTo("#inputs")
    , input = $("<input>").appendTo(div);
  input.googleSuggest({ service: "web" });
```

Comment: Why all the downvotes?  This is my second question on this site...

Comment: I almost wrote the complete answer myself as can be seen here [link](http://jsfiddle.net/883xbxdy/) (the jsfiddle that i posted earlier) Learn how to read instead of trashing a newbies reputation...

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement a google suggest-like input field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10795843/how-to-implement-a-google-suggest-like-input-field).

Comment: @Groo Nah, my question is about styling so no duplicate, that link does solve the second part, thanks for that :)

Answer (score 1):

Your custom css in the linked fiddle is creating problems. Removing all the css and adding external jquery-ui.css makes the dropdown appear correctly (as seen in [this fork of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5kh6gkje/)).

Basically, you only need:

```
// html placeholder for the input
<div id="inputs"></div>
```

and

```
// js init code
var input = $("<input>").appendTo($("#inputs"));
input.googleSuggest({ service: "web" });
```

Also, your other question has already been answered in this thread: [How to implement a google suggest-like input field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10795843/how-to-implement-a-google-suggest-like-input-field) It's a neat trick accomplished by overlaying two input fields one above the other one, with the lower one disabled and set to the value of first suggested entry.

Comment: Your fork is the standard script... My question is about how to get the custom styling. But thanks for answering the second part of my question!